# Haskell Snap rendering JSON from route

Tags: json, haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I'm new to Snap and Haskell. I am attempting to turn this output:

`[("LDPNLNDQQFHUKIWZII",2191.12),("NLNDQQFHUKIWZIIXDC",2195.0696),("NZRAIEUALDPNLNDQQFH",2192.0503)]`

into JSON. So I know the type is [(String, Double)], but that doesn't help me with the error message arising from GHCi when entering `writeJSON [("LDPNLNDQQFHUKIWZII",2191.12),("NLNDQQFHUKIWZIIXDC",2195.0696),("NZRAIEUALDPNLNDQQFH",2192.0503)]`:

`` No instance for (MonadSnap m0) arising from a use of `writeJSON'
    The type variable `m0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance MonadSnap m =>
               MonadSnap (Control.Monad.Trans.Cont.ContT c m)
        -- Defined in `snap-core-0.9.5.0:Snap.Internal.Instances'
      instance (MonadSnap m, Control.Monad.Trans.Error.Error e) =>
               MonadSnap (Control.Monad.Trans.Error.ErrorT e m)
        -- Defined in `snap-core-0.9.5.0:Snap.Internal.Instances'
      instance MonadSnap m =>
               MonadSnap (Control.Monad.Trans.List.ListT m)
        -- Defined in `snap-core-0.9.5.0:Snap.Internal.Instances'
      ...plus 8 others
    In the expression: writeJSON x
    In an equation for `it': it = writeJSON x ``

I'm not married to the current data structure (I just created it to clump an amino acid sequence with its mass). Ideally I would get JSON data that looks like this:

`{ "LDPNLNDQQFHUKIWZII":2191.12, "NLNDQQFHUKIWZIIXDC":2195.0696, "NZRAIEUALDPNLNDQQFH":2192.0503 }`

The output, `[("LDPNLNDQQFHUKIWZII",2191.12),("NLNDQQFHUKIWZIIXDC",2195.0696),("NZRAIEUALDPNLNDQQFH",2192.0503)]`, is calculated by a function that takes two pieces of input from the user: an original peptide sequence, and a weight (the program finds fragments from the peptide sequence that equal the entered weight).

Any help/direction is appreciated. Thanks!

## ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

I generated the app using `snap init barebones`. Here is what the handler looks like. I am getting the error at the `writeJSON result` line. I am intending on using the getParam lines, but to start I was just trying to get the JSON response.

```
possibleMatches :: Snap ()
possibleMatches = do
  peptideSequence <- getParam "peptide_sequence"
  weight          <- getParam "weight"
  let sequence = "V(3D)NK(3F)NKEXCNZRAIEUALDPNLNDQQFHUKIWZIIXDC"
  let weight = 2194.9
  let results = calculationResults weight sequence
  let result = take 1 [ seq | (seq,wt) <- results ]
  maybe (writeBS "must specify params in URL")
         writeJSON result
```

The error from the compiler is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Maybe a0'
                with actual type `[([Char], Float)]'
```

So I need to figure out how to deal with Maybe. I'm reading on it but some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are the functions `toJSNO` and `writeJSON` coming from?

Comment: oh excuse me. the stack trace is correct, it's the writeJSON function coming from Snap.Extras.JSON. toJSON was another option I was investigating from the json package, Text.JSON (similarly, no luck).

Comment: Can you put a bit more code?  Is this in one of your handlers?  It seems because the problem is you need to specify the instance of `MonadSnap` you are using but the compiler can't deduce it from the code you have.  The default `MonadSnap` you'll be in if you just use when snap generates when you type `snap init default` would be `Handler App App`.  If you've put this function in another monad it may be a problem.

Comment: Okay, I'll an idiot.  You said you entered it to ghci. You need to say what the monad is.  This could be something like `:: AppHandler App App (Either String a)` but you'll have to replace a with what you are parsing the JSON to.  But then you'll have to define App type.  I don't know if you can do `AppHandler () ()` or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeJSON` has the type

```
writeJSON :: (MonadSnap m, ToJSON a) => a -> m ()
```

where the `a` and the `m` must be resolved to specific types before the compiler can run the code. You can certainly use your object of type `[(String, Double)]` as the input because `String` has an instance of `ToJSON`, as does `Double`, as do any pair of things with `ToJSON` instances (i.e. `instance (ToJSON a, ToJSON b) => ToJSON (a, b)`), and finally as do lists of things with `ToJSON` instances (i.e. `instance ToJSON v => ToJSON [a]`).

So the problem is entirely in trying to determine what `m` is. The compiler is complaining that as long as `m` is "anything" it cannot be sure that it's an instance of `MonadSnap`. We can reassure the type checker at least by just asserting it is so

```
>>> :t writeJSON [("foo", 3)] :: MonadSnap m => m ()
writeJSON [("foo", 3.0)] :: MonadSnap m => m ()
```

But we need to pick a concrete choice of `m` before we can *run* it. If you have a test application which uses `MonadSnap` then you can embed this line of code there, for instance.

For testing, however, you probably should just use the function that `writeJSON` depends upon: `encode` from [`Data.Aeson`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson.html).

```
>>> encode [("foo", 3.0)]
"[[\"foo\",3.0]]"
```

Comment: this is getting me on the way, thanks for the help. I added some additional info. It seems to be my understanding of `Maybe` that is lacking.

Comment: That problem just seems to be that you passed something to `maybe` that wasn't wrapped in a `Maybe`. In particular, `Just :: a -> Maybe a` wraps up `Maybe`s and `maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` "unwraps" them. You passed `result` in as the third parameter and it's not wrapped in a `Maybe` so the compiler rejects it.

Comment: Ah hah! `writeJSON $ Just (results)`! Awesome, thanks so much. Now I just need to figure out how to render it as an object instead of an array of arrays.

Comment: You can write your own ToJSON instance, use Data.Map.Map or the function `object`.